# How to get dynamically selected value from material ui autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

We can get TextField value dynamically with `[evt.target.name]: evt.target.value` but
How can I get Autocomplete **selected value dynamically**, Like bellow example:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button'

const brands = ['niki', 'adidas', 'ramond', 'oliver', 'zara', 'casely']
const categories = ['pant', 'shirt']

const inputItems = [
    { label: 'Product Name',    type: 'text',   name: 'name' },
    { label: 'Brand',           type: 'text',   name: 'brand',    options: brands },
    { label: 'Category',        type: 'text',   name: 'category', options: categories },
    { label: 'Price',           type: 'number', name: 'price' },
    { label: 'Description',     type: 'text',   name: 'description' },
    { label: 'Image',           type: 'text',   name: 'image' },
]
const inputItemsObj = {}
inputItems.forEach(item => inputItemsObj[item.name] = '')


const Products = () => {
const [ fields, setFields ] = useState(inputItemsObj)
const [ fieldsError, setFieldsError ] = useState(inputItemsObj)


const changeHandler = (evt, newValue, action, option ) => {
    setFields({ ...fields,[evt.target.name]: evt.target.value })
}
const submitHandler = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault()

    console.log(fields)
}

return (
    <form noValidate onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        {inputItems.map(({label, type, name, options}, key) => (name === 'category' || name === 'brand') ? (
            <Autocomplete key={key}
                options={options}
                getOptionLabel={option => option}
                renderInput={ params => <TextField {...params}
                    label={label}
                    placeholder={label}
                    type={type}
                    fullWidth
                    margin='dense'
                    InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                    name={name}

                    error={!fields[name] || !!fieldsError[name]}
                    helperText={fieldsError[name]}
                />}
                name={name}
                value={options[0]}
                onChange={changeHandler}
            />
            ) : (
            <TextField key={key}
                label={label}
                placeholder={label}
                type={type}
                fullWidth
                autoFocus={key === 0}
                margin='dense'
                InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                name={name}
                value={fields[name]}
                onChange={changeHandler}
                multiline
                rows={name === 'description' ? 3 : 1}

                error={!fields[name] || !!fieldsError[name]}
                helperText={fieldsError[name]}
            />
        ))}

            <Button type='submit' variant='contained' >Submit</Button>
    </form>
    )
}
export default Products
```

Comment: How can we add **newValue** in setFields() method ? 

`setFields({ 
  ...fields,
  [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value, 
  [evt.target.name]:newValue              // it not works
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second value of onChange will give you a list of all the selected values.

```js
function(event: React.SyntheticEvent, value: T | Array<T>, reason: string, details?: string) => void
```

So in your example use `newValue` rather than `evt` in your `changeHandler`

More info found here: https://mui.com/api/autocomplete/

Edit: I don't think you will be able to get the *name* from `evt.target.name` so some solution like this should work.

```js
const changeHandler = (name) => (evt, newValue, action, option ) => {
  // Also as you are updating/adding to state a callback should be used in setFields     
  setFields((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: newValue })) 
}
```

Then in the Autocomplete:

```js
            <Autocomplete key={key}
                //...other props
                onChange={changeHandler(name)}
            />
```

Comment: the 2nd arg give the selected value but how I add it in `setFields({ ...fields, ?? })` method ?

Comment: Something like that should work. However, the `evt.target.name` will not get the name you set on the autocomplete (I don't think, but could be wrong). So you will have to pass the name some other way. eg. 
`const changeHandler = (name) => (evt, newValue, action, option ) => {
    setFields((prevState) =>({ ...fields, [name]: newValue }))
}`
Then in the autoComplete: 
`onChange={changeHandler(name)}`

 Also as you are updating/adding to state a callback should be used in `setFields`. I will update my answer to reflect this

Comment: Thanks 'Dan James':

Now I can do this 2 ways: 
  1. onChange={(evt, newValue) => changeHandler(evt, name, newValue)}   : Your Way

  2. <Autocomplete id={name} />     [evt.target.id.split('-').shift()]: newValue

Thanks, to you